# how to access tableview cell

Tags: ios, button, tableview

i have a menu that contain 6 cells 1st one contain `UIViewController` the second contain `UITableView`

when i click the first cell a new page appear,and  it contain a button
when i click this button i want access to the second cell from the Menu, that contain a tableView

Comment: I dont get it what you ask for ..Please edit your question with relevent information,what you want to achieve etc

Answer (score 4):

// use this code for to Refresh or delete or insert TableviewCell

```
// reloading cell
NSIndexPath *tmpIndexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpIndexpath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

// inserting cell
NSIndexPath *tmpIndexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpIndexpath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

// deleting cell
 NSIndexPath *tmpIndexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpIndexpath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Comment: @kokio : Can you share the app screen shots. how it is appearing? so that i can help you according that

Answer (score 2):

As much i understand your question you want to move from a tableview to other view on click..So,you have to use code similar to this..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Detail *img1=[[Detail alloc]initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:Nil];
    img1.labelString = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self presentViewController:img1 animated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write following coed in your `UIButton` Tapped Method.

```
-(void) ButtonTapped:(UIButton *) sender
{
        NSIndexPath *indexpathNew = [self.tblView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[sender superview]];

      NSLog(@"%@",indexpathNew.row);
}
```

`indexpathNew` is return `indextPath` of selected button of cell.

Try my code i might be helpful to you.